# Как передвинуть маркер в google map Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

подскажите пожалуйста как передвинуть или удалить маркер в google map Android

```
        final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
                marker.position(new LatLng(0,0));
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(MyGraphics.getBitMap(0xffff0000)));
                final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
                marker.position(new LatLng(0,0));
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(MyGraphics.getBitMap(0xffff0000)));
                marker.draggable(true);
                mMap.addMarker(marker);

                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                       // !!!!! ЗДЕСЬ ХОЧУ ПЕРЕДВИНУТЬ МАРКЕР, на или удалить старый и создать новый
                        marker.position(latLng);
                        //mMap.addMarker(marker); Маркер добавляется но не сдвигается как правильно?
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используется нативный маркер то

```
   public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                            marker.setMap(null);
                            marker.position(latLng);
                            mMap.addMarker(marker);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил так.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                mMap.clear();
                marker.position(latLng);
                mMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
        });
```